# Select only certain values from binding source to be displayed in combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I am attempting to manipulate a combobox to only show certain values that I desire out of a binding source.  Here is the code I currently have.

```
 provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    datafile = "C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop\Halton\HaltonProject.accdb"
    connString = provider & datafile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE (SP_Level <>  0)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader


    Dim Full_Name As String

    While dr.Read
        Full_Name = dr("Full_Name").ToString
        SP_Emp1.Items.Add(Full_Name)
        SP_Emp2.Items.Add(Full_Name)
        SP_Emp3.Items.Add(Full_Name)
        SP_Emp4.Items.Add(Full_Name)
    End while
```

As it stands this code looks at the "SP_Level" and filters out any employees who have a "0" listed there.  The string "Full_Name" returns all the employees who are listed as other that "0" in the "SP_Level" column.

I would like to leave the combobox databound to the EmployeeBindingSource while only displaying the new filtered "Full_Name" strings produced by the code above.  I have tried filtering the bindingsource but that only returns the first alphabetical string to match then stops.  I'm sure there is a simple solution I just can't seem to find it

[Data bound combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkl4o.png)

[Access table used in data-binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMCBg.jpg)

I am quite new to VB programming so I apologize if this is poorly worded.  Please let me know if I can better explain anything.

Comment: Is SP_Level a string?  There's not reason to concatenate that.  It's just `WHERE (SP_Level <> 0)`  Your loop makes little sense.  userFound and Full_Name will only be the last items in the loop, unless you aren't showing us everything.

Comment: Each row represents a new filter `SP >0`, `PB >0` etc.  Rather than trying to get one source to do that, you could create different Views for each criteria and bind to that.  Multiple skills like that should be a 1:m table of its own.

Comment: Thanks for that tip LarsTech.  I've modified the OP to show what I had tried initially, which does populate the combobox the way that I would like it to be, but obviously it cannot be databound and allow the values to be programmatically changed.  Plutonix - That's correct, I will have to do this filtering for each scenario.  I'm not sure I understand your suggestions though, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have/ use the same `DataSource` for each row/skill set, you just need to filter each accordingly.  This creates a `DataView` for each criteria rather than manually filtering out some from the source or using a new query to create only slightly different sources:

```
' my fake table
Dim colors As String() = {"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Orange", "White"}
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("color", GetType(String))

For Each s As String In colors
    dt.Rows.Add(s)
Next

' create a view for each level and bind it
Dim SPView As New DataView(dt, "Color <> 'Red'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
ComboBox1.DataSource = SPView
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "color"

Dim XPView As New DataView(dt, "Color <> 'Green'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
ComboBox2.DataSource = XPView
ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "color"

Dim ZPView As New DataView(dt, "Color <> 'Blue'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
ComboBox3.DataSource = ZPView
ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "color"
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, I was stuck on this for quite some time.  I was hoping it was just some new syntax that I had not seen/heard of before!  I greatly appreciate it, enjoy the rest of your day.